# how to mock an exported function with sinon.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai, sinon, sinon-chai

So I have a file called `article.js` that looks like this:

```js
import a from 'indefinite';

function formatArticle(value) {
  return a(value);
}

export { formatArticle };
export default formatArticle;
```

And a file called `index.js` that looks like this:

```js
import formatArticle from './article';

const format = (value, incomingFormat) => {
  if (incomingFormat === 'indefinite') {
    return formatArticle(value);
  }

  return value;
};

export default format;
```

I am trying to test that the formatArticle function that I am importing is getting called when it should. I am using `sinon` and `chai` for this. Here is the test file:

```js
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import sinonChai from 'sinon-chai';

import format from './index';
import * as article from './article';

chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('format', () => {
    describe('article', () => {
        describe(`when incoming format is 'indefinite'`, () => {
            const value = 'some value';
            const indefinite = 'indefinite';

            let formatArticleSpy;

            beforeEach(() => {
                formatArticleSpy = sinon.spy(article, 'formatArticle');
                format(value, indefinite);
            });

            it('should call formatArticle', () => {
                expect(formatArticleSpy).to.have.been.calledWith(value);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

However whenever I run the test suite it tells me:

`AssertionError: expected formatArticle to have been called with arguments some value`

What am I doing wrong in this setup? Is using a spy the correct way to try to do this? I have tried using sinon.stub as well and I get the same result.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

sinon.js use [Link Seams](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/) to stub a standalone function. The `formatArticle` function for your case.

E.g.

`article.js`:

```js
import a from './indefinite';

function formatArticle(value) {
  return a(value);
}

export default formatArticle;
```

`indefinite.js`:

```js
export default function a(value) {
  return 'real data';
}
```

`index.js`:

```js
import formatArticle from './article';

const format = (value, incomingFormat) => {
  if (incomingFormat === 'indefinite') {
    return formatArticle(value);
  }

  return value;
};

export default format;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('61104001', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const value = 'some value';
    const indefinite = 'indefinite';
    const formatArticleStub = sinon.stub().returns('fake data');
    const format = proxyquire('./', {
      './article': { default: formatArticleStub },
    }).default;
    const actual = format(value, indefinite);
    sinon.assert.match(actual, 'fake data');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(formatArticleStub, value);
  });
  // you can do the rest
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
  61104001
    ✓ should pass (2259ms)


  1 passing (2s)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |   72.73 |       50 |   33.33 |   72.73 |                   
 article.ts    |   66.67 |      100 |       0 |   66.67 | 4                 
 indefinite.ts |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 2                 
 index.ts      |   83.33 |       50 |     100 |   83.33 | 8                 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/61104001