# nodejs - using sinon to stub a response

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I have the following `nodejs` code. I am trying to write unit tests for `module.exports.handle` for error scenario. All I am trying to do is mock `processData` function so that it returns error.

```
module.exports.handle = async (event) => {
  const { body } = event;

    try {
      const response = await processData(body);
      if (response)
      {
         return { 201 };
      }
    catch (error) {
      return {
        500
      };
    }
  } 
};


async function processData() {
  try {
    const response = await externalServiceCall();
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error');
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you try? What test result did you get?

Comment: `const processDataStub = sinon.stub(processData);
    processDataStub.resolves(expectedResponse);`
I am always getting .resolves is not a function

Comment: The API is `sinon.stub(object, "method");`, you can't stub a standalone function.

Comment: so lets say `const processData = require('./processData');` how do i stub this? processData is the only function i am exporting from the file.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104001/how-to-mock-an-exported-function-with-sinon-js

Comment: could not figure that out. i modified the standalone function by wrapping it inside an object.     `const processDataStub = sinon.stub(wrapperObj,'processData').returns('fake data');`
but now when i call `expect(processDataStub.called).to.be.true;` it returns false